# Set agent monitor window size in Netlogo

Tags: netlogo

I use a monitor window and mouse coordinates to get a closer look at certain parts of my model. Is there any way to set the size of the agent monitor window somewhere in the `inspect` procedure? If the magnification level could be set at the same time, that would be even better. I couldn't find anything in the dictionary. I know that you can set the size of the static monitors by opening up the text version of the model by playing with the dimensions as below:

```
MONITOR
610
1074
791
1119
NIL
int-step-len
17
1
11
```

However, I can't figure out a way to do this for a dynamic window, and I'd like to not have to manually resize and zoom in. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I don't think there's anything built-into the language. However, you may be able to design a custom widget with an extension. See https://github.com/CRESS-Surrey/eXtraWidgets#readme

Comment: That looks promising, I'll fiddle around and see if I can make it work. Thanks Matt!

Comment: From memory, the eXtraWidgets is only input widgets, not reporting widgets, though it might have been extended further